# Cannot save more than 256 records R2DBC: Spring WebFlux Cannot exchange messages because the request queue limit is exceeded

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-webflux

I have below code which inserts data into postgres database:

```
if (employeeList == null || employeeList.isEmpty())
            return Flux.empty();

        return Flux.fromIterable(employeeList)
                .doOnNext(employee -> {
                    employee.setParentResourceId(parentResourceId);
                    employee.setCreatedBy(userId);
                })
                .map(employeeMapper::entityFromModel)
                .flatMap(employeeRepository::save)
                .map(employeeMapper::fromEntity);
```

Above code works fine for `employeeList <= 256`, when I try to insert more than `256` records I get
`Cannot exchange messages because the request queue limit is exceeded` exception

I have researched quite abit and replaced above code with below code:

```
Flux<Employee> employeeFlux = Flux.create(emitter -> {
            for (Employee employee : employeeList) {
                emitter.next(employee);
            }
        }, FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.BUFFER);
        return employeeFlux 
                .doOnNext(employee -> {
                    employee.setParentResourceId(parentResourceId);
                    employee.setCreatedBy(userId);
                })
                .map(employeeMapper::entityFromModel)
                .flatMap(employeeRepository::save)
                .map(employeeMapper::fromEntity);
```

This change didn't help, I'm facing same exception.

Is there any other strategy to handle this situation in WebFlux. I want the code to be reactive.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql/issues/360)? So `concatMap` instead of `flatMap`?

Comment: Yes, that too doesn't work :( I have tried by replacing `flatMap(employeeRepository::save)` with `concatMap(employeeRepository::save)`, Im using postgres version 0.8.6.RELEASE

Comment: It was my mistake, using concatMap actually works as @M.Deinum suggested thank you!, I had not clean the project after performing clean on project concatMap works like a charm for saving List with more than 256 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `flatMap` which works concurrently you should use `concatMap` which works on a one to one basis. See [this issue](https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql/issues/360) which explains that in a bit more detail.

```java
return Flux.fromIterable(employeeList)
            .doOnNext(employee -> {
                employee.setParentResourceId(parentResourceId);
                employee.setCreatedBy(userId);
            })
            .map(employeeMapper::entityFromModel)
            .concatMap(employeeRepository::save)
            .map(employeeMapper::fromEntity);
```